# Unable to get google graphs to display when trying to implement MVC pattern

Tags: php, mysqli, google-visualization

Hoping someone can find a solution to my problem.  I am trying to create a dashboard using google maps and PHP.  I was able to display the graphs before I tried putting it into the MVC pattern and now all I get is errors. (the code is separated into their respective folders Model, View, and Controller with an index file in the root directory). Here is a the code I have so far

Index

```
<?php

include_once ("Design/includes.php");

$controller = new Controller();
$controller->invoke();
?>
```

Controller

```
<?php

class Controller {
public $model;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->model = new tableModel();

}

public function invoke()
{
    $this->model -> tableData();
    include 'view/homeScreen.php';
}

}

?>
```

Model (this is for the table, another model is in the same folder but it is exactly the same)

```
<?php

class tableModel {

public function tableData(){
    global $con;

$result = mysqli_query ( $con, "SELECT fk_EXECUTION_LAB_MACHINE as LAB_MACHINE,    COUNT(fk_EXECUTION_LAB_MACHINE) as TOTAL
                            FROM EXECUTION_QUEUE
                            WHERE fk_EXECUTION_LAB_MACHINE IS NOT NULL and WEEK (TEST_START_TIME) = WEEK( current_date ) -1 AND YEAR( TEST_START_TIME) = YEAR( current_date )
                            GROUP BY fk_EXECUTION_LAB_MACHINE order by count(fk_EXECUTION_LAB_MACHINE) desc;");



$rows = array();

$table = array();

$table['cols'] = array(

    // Labels for chart/column titles
    array('label' => 'LAB_MACHINE', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'TOTAL', 'type' => 'number')

);

//Getting results array and populating table
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $temp = array();
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['LAB_MACHINE']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['TOTAL']);
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

//Get table in JSON format
$table['rows'] = $rows;

$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
echo $jsonTable;
return $jsonTable;

mysqli_close ( $con );


    }
}
?>
```

and here is the view

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


var Dash = {

        widget : {},

        render : {

            pie : function() {

                var view = new google.visualization.DataView(Dash.data.pieEg);

                var options = {
                        animation : {duration : 300},
                        chartArea : {width : '100%', height : '70%'},
                        is3D: 'true',
                        title : 'Pie Chart',
                        tooltip : {showColorCode : true}
                        };

                        Dash.widget.pie.draw(view, options);
                },


            table : function() {

                Dash.widget.table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                    chartType: 'Table',
                    dataTable: Dash.data.tableEg,

                    options: {
                        allowHtml : true
                    },
                    containerId: 'table_div'
                });

                Dash.widget.table.draw();
            }
        },

        util : {

            bootstrap : function(){
                Dash.util.prepareData();
                Dash.render.table();
                Dash.util.createWidgets();
                Dash.util.refreshCharts();
            },

            createWidgets : function(){
                Dash.widget.pie = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('pie_div'));
            },

            refreshCharts : function(tableEg){
                if (!tableEg || tableEg.length === 0) {
                    tableEg = [1,2];
                }

                Dash.render.pie(tableEg.slice(0));
            },

            prepareData : function(){

                Dash.data = {};

                var tableData = $.ajax({
                    url: "tableModel.php",
                    dataType:"json",
                    async: false
                }).responseText;

                Dash.data.tableEg = new google.visualization.DataTable(tableData);


                var chartData = $.ajax({
                    url: "pieModel.php",
                    dataType:"json",
                    async: false
                }).responseText;                       

                Dash.data.pieEg = new google.visualization.DataTable(chartData);

            }
        }
        };

        google.load('visualization', '1', {
            'packages':['corechart'],
            'callback': Dash.util.bootstrap
        });

        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="row1">

        <div id="pie_div"
            style="width: 410px; height: 410px; display: inline-block"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="row2" style="width: 900px">
        <div id="table_div" style="width: 700px; display: inline-block"></div>
        <div id="gauge" style="display: inline-block; float: right"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As I said earlier, the graphs worked fine when I had it just with the view and the table data in one folder but now I have put it into MVC style it no longer works. here is the errors I am getting

`{"cols":[{"label":"LAB_MACHINE","type":"string"},{"label":"TOTAL","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"LIT-QAVIST-20"},{"v":1}]},{"c":[{"v":"LIT-QAVIST-25"},{"v":1}]}]}`**`Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Users\n0237569\workspace\Dashboard MVC\Design\model\tableModel.php on line 11`**

**`Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\Users\n0237569\workspace\Dashboard MVC\Design\model\tableModel.php on line 28`**
`{"cols":[{"label":"LAB_MACHINE","type":"string"},{"label":"TOTAL","type":"number"}],"rows":[]}`

**`Warning: include(view/homeScreen.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\n0237569\workspace\Dashboard MVC\Design\controller\Controller.php on line 17`**

**`Warning: include(): Failed opening 'view/homeScreen.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\Users\n0237569\workspace\Dashboard MVC\Design\controller\Controller.php on line 17`**

As you can see from the first error it is returning the data in json but then im not sure what is going on next.

Here is the contents of the include folder as the last two errors make reference to it

includes

```
<?php
require_once "Design/config.php";
require_once "Design/connection.php";
require_once "Design/model/pieModel.php";
require_once "Design/model/tableModel.php";
require_once "Design/controller/Controller.php";

?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Warning: include(view/homeScreen.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\n0237569\workspace\Dashboard MVC\Design\controller\Controller.php on line 17


Warning: include(): Failed opening 'view/homeScreen.php' for inclusion     (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\Users\n0237569\workspace\Dashboard     MVC\Design\controller\Controller.php on line 17
```

These errors are being caused by this line in your controller

```
include 'view/homeScreen.php';
```

because inside your controller you are in the `Controller` folder so you need to look up a level, i.e.

```
include '../view/homeScreen.php';
```

In your tableModel

```
return $jsonTable;

mysqli_close ( $con );
```

The `mysqli_close( $con );` part in the bottom of your `tableModel` is useless as you are already `return`ing just above it. PHP will automagically close the connection when the request is finished, but it might be worth closing it yourself if it is no longer needed.

You should wrap some logic around your MySQL functions to debug the query.

You can try something like

```
if( !$result ) { die(mysqli_error($con));
```

You should consider using PDO, and taking a look at some existing MVC frameworks to get a better idea about the MVC pattern, and how they handle routing and autoloading classes etc.

Comment: you were correct about the two errors, I added the folder to the controller and now the errors are gone (just displays the JSON now but still will not display the view with the graphs) Im pretty new to this so will have a look at PDO and see what I can do.